# How to define static class with future init

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to define a static DB class in my application.

```
class DB {
  Database? _database;

  Future<Database?> get instance async {
    if (_database != null) return _database;
    _database = await _initDB();
    return _database;
  }
}
```

But when I need this DB instance, it must init the DB class first, how to statically get this DB instance?

```
// now to get the db instance
final db = await DB().instance;

// actually I want to get the db instance
final db = await DB.instance;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since only static a variable can be accessed via a static method, you should do it like--

```
class DB {  
     static  Future<Database?> get instance async {
     // the first instance of database created by _initDB will be persisted in memory for any instance of class DB.
     final _database = await _initDB();
     return _database;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think if you change both **_database** and **instance** to static it will work:

```
class DB {
  static Database? _database;

  static Future<Database?> get instance async {
    if (_database != null) return _database;
    _database = await _initDB();
    return _database;
  }
}
```

And you can use it like:

```
final db = await DB.instance;
```